# Swithching tables based on Conditions in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 3 tables, I want to switch tables on the basis of certain field in one table.

```
Table 1 (ID_table1, Type, Child_Id)

Table 2 (Id, table2_Value_1(String))

Table 3 (Id, Table3_Value_1(String))
```

Here I want to select value from `table 2` or `table 3` on the basis of the `Type` in `table1` and use the `Child_Id` as the foreign key that relates `table 2` and `table 3`.

```
if(Table1.type=="a") then Table 2 else table 3
```

I wants to do this in hibernate.

Comment: This question is confusing. Simple if after fetching the types solves the whole thing in my mind. Not sure what answer you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you can create two type of query.

check the result of IF

and on the basis of result

you call one of query before created

Comment: Doing that increase the load very much.if there r 100 entry in table 1, we must execute 101 queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field, conditioned by type of table1.

Comment: Can you suggest any help tutorial to do that..??